# What is the safest way to run .exe files on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, package-management, playonlinux, antivirus

I have already tried wine, but that just gave me a mess!! But I never tried PlayOnLinux yet, but I think it will just cause the same issue! I already tried using a Windows 10 ISO for a VM, but it took forever and failed to boot. If someone could help find the safest way to run .exe  files **virus-free** please.

And before, it broke my Package System!

Comment: PlayOnLinux is specifically designed not to make a mess. Every program can have separate prefix and it's very easy to completely delete entire prefix when you stop needing it. I suggest you give it a try if your .exe's are supported by WINE.

Answer (score 3):

There is no (safe or unsafe) way to run `.exe` files on Linux systems ... "virus-free"" or not ...
`.exe` files are Windows executables, to run them you have to use `wine` or a Windows VM.

Maybe you did not setup the Windows VM properly ... it needs a bit of time to learn everything.
I recommend to use KVM or VirtualBox for this purpose, both solutions are available in Ubuntu.

VirtualBox is the most easy application to learn about and use virtualization and `qemu` (KVM) with `virt-manager`, which provides a better performance, is better for more advanced users.